# how do I merge 2 images with the same file names into one in a batch process? Is there a prgram that can do this?

Tags: batch, images, pictures, combine

Can anyone help me here. I am trying to make a collection of DVD covers. I have multiple images for the different covers and multiple images for the different spine lettering. Each cover .jpg has the same name as its corresponding Spine Jpg. I just need to know how to combine these images together in a batch process as I have 900 of them and joining them together one by one would take a long time. Is there a program that can do this with the minimum of fuss? I mostly use Photoshop but I have not found a way of doing this.

Comment: You could do that with Imagemagick. There are many examples in their forum. http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewforum.php?f=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet would likely be to use [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) (which is a cross-platform program for manipulating images from the command line) and some custom scripting. That said, I am not sure if this would be a "minimum fuss" solution for you or not

If you are interested in trying ImageMagick, you can get current versions from the [downloads page](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php), though you may have scroll a bit to find something suitable for you. You didn't mention which operating system you're using, but for Windows specifically, the default `Q16-x64` build should likely be fine.

**Using ImageMagick**

Once ImageMagick is installed, for combining images, you can use the `convert` utility.

Assuming we have a set of images labeled e.g. *image_front.jpg*, *image_back.jpg* and *image_spine.jpg* and that they're all the same height, we can use `convert` with the [+append](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#append) option to stitch them together horizontally:

```
convert image_front.jpg image_spine.jpg image_back.jpg +append image_combined.jpg
```

In this case, *image_combined.jpg* is our final cover consisting of the given images in order.

---

**Windows Convert**

Note that Windows has a built-in `convert` command which has nothing to do with ImageMagick. This may cause some confusion or other minor issues if you're using Windows and aren't careful.

Regardless, if you wish to use the ImageMagick `convert` utility on Windows as demonstrated above, you will need to register your ImageMagick installation folder (*ex*. `C:\path\to\imagemagick`) in your Windows `Path` environment variable.

Otherwise, you will need to specify the full path to `convert` each time you call it (*ex.* `C:\path\to\imagemagick\convert.exe`).

---

**Automation**

Since ImageMagick works via the command line, it lends itself to automation through scripting. While there are various ways to approach this, I have provided a simple example using Windows batch below.

For consistency, I will be using a naming scheme similar to the `convert` example from earlier. I am also assuming all the files to convert appear in the same initial directory as well.

*An Example Batch Solution*

For this example, the first step is to create a list of "base" file names ("extensions" such as `_front.jpg`, `_spine.jpg` and `_back.jpg` will be added in the batch script).

This list could be called anything you like but I will be referring to it as *files.txt*. Assuming the cover images are e.g. `image_01_front.jpg`, `image_01_spine.jpg`, `image_01_back.jpg`, etc. and that there are four groups of images, *files.txt* would have the following contents:

```
image_01
image_02
image_03
image_04
```

Note that this list should have no duplicates. Likewise, there should be no blank lines. Assuming these requirements are met, this list could then be used as input for the following example batch file:

```
@echo off

@rem Create some folders to hold our images after processing.
if not exist processed mkdir processed
if not exist combined mkdir combined

@rem We use %%~A below to access the strings returned from our list.
@rem %cd% is a special variable representing the current directory.

@rem For each item in our list...
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%A in ("%cd%\files.txt") do (

  @rem Use ImageMagick to combine our images.
  @rem We are concatenating strings here (%%~A and e.g. "_front.jpg").
  @rem This is the same as writing ex. "image_01_front.jpg".

  convert %%~A_front.jpg %%~A_spine.jpg %%~A_back.jpg +append %%~A_combined.jpg

  @rem Sort our images to the appropriate local folders after conversion.
  move %%~A_front.jpg .\processed
  move %%~A_spine.jpg .\processed
  move %%~A_back.jpg .\processed
  move %%~A_combined.jpg .\combined

)

echo Script completed.
pause
```

This script can be saved as e.g. *merge.bat*. Assuming this batch file resides in the same directory as *files.txt* (along with the images listed in that file), it should be possible to double-click *merge.bat* and simply have it process all the images in the list (assuming nothing goes awry).

**Script Notes**

- The given script is just an example, obviously. It might require some tweaking for your specific situation/desires.
- Currently, the example batch file doesn't recurse sub-directories.
- `("%cd%\files.txt")` can be replaced with e.g. `("C:\path\to\files.txt")`.
- `%%~A` is extremely noteworthy, as it ends up representing each string (in turn) listed in *files.txt*.
- While exact file names are less important (the `convert/+append` command can take almost any arbitrary name), for automation, they should have a consistent structure. If you need to alter a large number of file names at once on Windows, you might be interested in [Bulk Rename Utility](http://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/Main_Intro.php).
- While batch is passable, another language I might suggest is [Python](https://www.python.org/). It's cross-platform and, while it can take more code to deal with files, it can be preferable over batch in many other ways.

---

**Generating File Lists**

Real-world file lists are likely to be slightly more difficult to generate than four basic items. While it won't produce exactly what you need for the example above, if you're on Windows you can create a list of just file names and extensions with `dir /b > files.txt` at a command prompt open to the same directory as your image files. This will get you at least 50% of the way in most cases.

Similarly, third-party text editors such as [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) (Windows) can have useful features. In the case of Notepad++, it supports [regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) as well as normal text replacement. Thus to make e.g.:

```
image_01_back.jpg
image_01_front.jpg
image_01_spine.jpg
image_02_back.jpg
image_02_front.jpg
image_02_spine.jpg
image_03_back.jpg
image_03_front.jpg
image_03_spine.jpg
image_04_back.jpg
image_04_front.jpg
image_04_spine.jpg
merge.bat
randomfile.extra
files.txt
```

into:

```
image_01
image_02
image_03
image_04
```

For Notepad++ you could:

1. Manually remove *merge.bat*, *randomfile.extra* and *files.txt*.
2. Use *Search* → *Replace...* ( <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> ) to eliminate extensions (.e.g. `.jpg`) via blank replacements, as well as, say, `_front` to give a set of base names for the batch script:

   ```
    image_01_back
   →image_01
    image_01_spine
    image_02_back
   →image_02
    image_02_spine
    image_03_back
   →image_03
    image_03_spine
    image_04_back
   →image_04
    image_04_spine
   ```
3. You could then switch to `Search Mode: Regular expression` to eliminate lines containing *_spine*:

[image: Notepad++ Regular Expression Replacement]

In the screenshot above, `.+spine$` selects all the lines with `_spine` at the end. You could eliminate all the lines containing `_back` with `.+back$` as well, leaving something like the following:

```
    image_01

    image_02

    image_03

    image_04
```

4. These blank lines could then be eliminated with *Edit* → *Line Operations* → *Remove Empty Lines*, leaving our final list for *files.txt*:

   ```
   image_01
   image_02
   image_03
   image_04
   ```

This may seem inefficient for four lines but since you say you have over 900 items, some variation on these steps might be worth considering.